# How to include an h file locally, without visual studio?

Tags: c++

I have a simple cpp code that uses `curl.h` as it's header file.
I use vscode, and not interested on linking via gui or w/e

How can I make the include statement work properly with the single project?
I got the header file from https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h
Folder structure is like this:

```
/Folder
+-> curl.h
+-> curli.cpp
```

the code:

```
#include "curl.h"

using namespace std;

#define YOUR_URL "https://www.insertyourURLhere.com/"
#define USER_AND_PWD "user:password"

static string gs_strLastResponse;

// Callback to gather the response from the server.  Comes in chunks (typically 16384 characters at a time), so needs to be stitched together.
size_t function_pt(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * /*stream*/)
{
 gs_strLastResponse += (const char*)ptr;
 return size * nmemb;
}

bool CallServerWithCurl(string strData1, strData2, string& strErrorDescription)
{
 CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
 if (curl == NULL)
 {
     strErrorDescription = "Unable to initialise Curl";
     return false;
 }

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, (YOUR_URL + "get_result").c_str());
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, MY_USER_AND_PWD);    // set user name and password for the authentication

 char* data1 = curl_easy_escape(curl, strData1.c_str(), 0);
 char* data2 = curl_easy_escape(curl, strData2.c_str(), 0);
 string strArguments = "id=" + data1 + "&task=" + data2;
 const char* my_data = strArguments.c_str();

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, my_data);
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(my_data));   // if we don't provide POSTFIELDSIZE, libcurl will strlen() by itself

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);     // enable verbose for easier tracing

  gs_strLastResponse = "";
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function_pt);        // set a callback to capture the server's response

 CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

 // we have to call twice, first call authenticates, second call does the work
 res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

 if (res != CURLE_OK)
 {
     strErrorDescription = "Curl call to server failed";
     return false;
 }
 if (!DoSomethingWithServerResponse(gs_strLastResponse))
 {
     strErrorDescription = "Curl call to server returned an unexpected response";
     return false;
 }

 // extract some transfer info
 double speed_upload, total_time;
 curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD, &speed_upload);
 curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &total_time);
 fprintf(stderr, "Speed: %.3f bytes/sec during %.3f seconds\n", speed_upload, total_time);

 curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

 return true;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "make the include work properly" ? You dont need more than `#include "curl.h"`

Comment: Note that header files have *nothing* to do with "linking". Header files are included (basically copy-pasted into the place of the `#include` directive) by the preprocessor before the code is even parsed, to form what is known as a [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). This translation unit is then parsed into either assembly code (which is assembled into an object file) or direct to an object file (without the assembly step). The object files are then linked together with the actual libraries to form the final executable program.

Comment: If the source file and the header file are in the same directory, all you need is that `#include "curl.h"` ...

Comment: did you try to compile and got error messages? Please include them in the question. Also consider to prepare a [mcve], basically only `#include "curl.h"  int main(){}` is required to see problems if there are any